# What did the prisoners in “Escape From New York” eat?

Tags: plot-explanation, escape-from-new-york

In John Carpenter's [*Escape From New York* (1981)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082340/), how and what did the prisoners eat?

I don't recall it being mentioned in the film, other than in one scene which spoke of some subterranean dwellers running low on food.

Comment: Presumably, animals.  Possibly rats.  Same family as squirrels.  They're edible if you're in a bind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### They are fed by the Government.

This is a maximum security prison (albeit a very large one) and there is reference in the [**script**](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Escape-From-New-York.html) to "food drops"

> PILOT - We have a visual sighting on it.  It's a crowd of prisoners in Central
>   Park.  They're waving at us.  **Signaling us in the food drop area.**
>   They're waving us down.

Apparently, drops are made monthly...

> GIRL IN CHOCK FULL O' NUTS - Crazies.  It's the **end of the month**.  They're out of food.

This is confirmed at the [**Official John Carpenter**](http://www.theofficialjohncarpenter.com/escape-from-new-york/) site

> Other than the **monthly food drops made by air** into Central Park these outcasts are left completely on their own to prey on each other.

Answer (score -4):

The Crazies who lived in the sewers—I'm guessing by the way they dragged Season Hubley's character, they eat people.

Also, formerly, before it's a prison, some would have had gardens and shops seeds. I'm guessing rat burgers and other vermin.